# How to use doxygen and JavaDoc for the same Java project

Tags: java, javadoc, doxygen

I would like to create two versions, one with doxygen and one with JavaDoc. However Javadoc does not have an option to exclude specific text parts from the documentation. So tags which are specific to doxygen are included, like `\mainpage` or `\page`

A workaround could be to use package-info.java for the core Javadoc of the API, and to put some additional documentation, release notes etc. for Doxygen in a file doxygen.html in the source folder (just where package.html was before JDK 5).

Or are there other options, which could even help to put the parts with some doxygen specific tags back to the package-info.html?

Answer (score 0):

If such doxygen tags are limited than let such tags getting generated in Java docs. Use some text processor to find and replace the tags, such text processor can be already available in unix env.